# ElasticSearch-NEST Query String Phrase

Tags: elasticsearch, query-string, nest

I have a problem with ElasticSearch query phrases.
My index document is;

```
    var person = new Person
    {
        Id = "4",
        Firstname = "ali ahmet",
        Lastname = "yazıcı"
    };
    var index = client.Index(person, x => x.Index("personindex"));
```

My search phrase is;

```
    var result = client.Search<Person>(s => s
        .From(0)
        .Size(10)
        .Query(q => q
            .SimpleQueryString(qs => qs
                .OnFields(new[]{"firstname","lastname"})
                .Query("\"ali ah*\"")
            )
        )
  );
```

Result document is empty. But when i change my phrase to

```
.Query("\"ali ahmet\"")
```

result is coming. Why return empty result from

```
.Query("\"ali ah*\"")
```

this phrase.

**EDIT**

**Person Class**

```
public class Person
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}
```

**Index mapping**

```
var response = client.CreateIndex("personindex", c => c
            .AddMapping<Person>(m => m.MapFromAttributes())
```

Comment: May you share index mapping and `Person` class as well?

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html#_simple_query_string_syntax) for simple query string:

> " wraps a number of tokens to signify a phrase for searching

When you are searching for `.Query("\"ali ah*\"")` actually it looks for phrase `ali ah*`, but `*` is not treated as wildcard character.

Chnage your NEST query to:

```
var result = client.Search<Person>(s => s
    .Explain()
    .From(0)
    .Size(10)
    .Query(q => q
        .QueryString(qs => qs
            .OnFields(new[] {"firstname", "lastname"})
            .Query("ali ah*")
        )
    ));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you Rob. But your query is equals with "ali or ah*" match. I don't want this. Word order is very important for me. First word must "ali" and second word is "ah*".

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = client.Search<Person>(s => s
.Explain()
.From(0)
.Size(10)
.Query(q => q
    .Match(qs => qs
        .OnFields(new[] {"firstname", "lastname"})
        .Query("ali ah*")
        .MinimumShouldMatch(100)
    )
));
```